# Not able to edit an iframe after contentWindow.document.close()

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, document

I'm developing a chrome extension where I'm trying to auto populate the fields/values in a form so that I need not type it explicitly. I'm trying to load the content during `window.onload`

```html
window.onload = function() {
  alert(document.getElementById('mce_0_ifr'));
  alert("Window loaded!");
  setTimeout(setText, 2000);    
};

function setText() {
 /**
 This logic of having it as 0 will not work always. When you create the same dialog for 
 the second time it's incrementing it's value by 1.
 **/
 alert("Inside set text");
 if(document.getElementById('mce_0_ifr') != null) {
        var doc = document.getElementById('mce_0_ifr').contentWindow.document;
  doc.open();
  doc.write('<b> Student details </b>');
  doc.write('<br><br> Student Name : ');
  doc.write('<br><br> Age : ');
  doc.write('<br><br> Class : ');
  doc.write('<br><br> Subjects interested : ');
  doc.write('<br><br> Extra caricular activities : ');
  doc.write('<br><br> Father's name : ');
  doc.write('<br><br> Mother's name : ');
  doc.write('<br><br> Maid's name : ');
  doc.write('')
  doc.close();
 }
}
```

After doing this, I'm not able to add content to the iframe with id `mce_0_ifr`. I would like to load the content (some default text) into the iframe on page load and should allow user's to edit it further. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After you close() a document, it finishes writing to that document. In order to write() again, you need to open() it again. In your case, opening it again will lose previously written contents.
Here is what I do. Open the document first and write basic HTML structure on it:

```
doc.open();
doc.write("<html><head></head><body></body></html>");
doc.close();
```

Now, you can manipulate the document by manipulating the DOM instead of writing directly to it:

```
var line=document.createElement("div");
line.innerHTML='<b> Student details </b>';
line.innerHTML=line.innerHTML+'<br><br> Student Name : <span id="student_name"></span>';
line.innerHTML=line.innerHTML+'<br><br> Age : <span id="student_age"></span>';
...
doc.body.append(line);
```

Furthermore, you can modify student_name and student_age by getting their DOM element and then changing it's value:

```
doc.getElementById("student_name").innerText="rm -rf star";
doc.getElementById("student_age").innerText="21";
```